Resistor Values for Optoisolator / NPN Circuit
I need to design a "Soft Power" circuit to turn on a power supply when the PFW line is high (5V). I came up with the following drawing, after using the following "sources" for inspiration:

Relay PN2222A: https://www.instructables.com/Design-a-Sustainable-Relay-Driving-Circuit-Using-B/
PC817 setup: Switching a 5V power relay with optocoupler

Here's how I came up with the parts/values:

R1:

ic (collector current) = Voltage / Rcoil 
ic = 4.6 (considering voltage drop) / 125 (Relay specification) 
ic = 36,8mA 
ib (base current) = ic / ßmin with ßmin = 35 for 2N2222 (datasheet).
ib = 36,8 / 35 = 1,051 mA
With VB = base voltage, VBE (base emitter voltage drop) = 0.7 (PN Junction) we come to
RB (base resistor) = (Vb-Vbe)/ib = (4.6-0.7)/ 1,051 = 3.7kOhm

R2: Suggested here https://forum.arduino.cc/t/chosing-the-right-resistor-on-an-optocoupler/68484
Q1: Suggested by https://www.instructables.com/Design-a-Sustainable-Relay-Driving-Circuit-Using-B/
D1: My own "guess"
K1: Based on my own research, I need a 5V DPST relay
F1: Additional fuse just for the monitor. F2 (not shown) is located between AC_L and AC_L_Fuse... "To Monitor" is basically going to be a C13 Receptacle for an old CRT monitor.

Am I missing something or did I make an error?


What is "PFW"?  (NB, You might also want to take a look at the sticky answer about drawing good diagrams ... you might want to work on the left-to-right flow, ground-is-down and so on, to make your diagrams easier to read.)

@jonathanjo The diode is forward biased during EMF so it is not under high voltage stress. The 4001 is ok.

@jonathanjo please explain how you see a 1N4001 will be over-voltage stressed in this situation. If you want my opinion; it won't because (a) it will see a reverse voltage of 5 volts when the relay coil is activated and, (b) it will forward conduct to the tune of a volt or so when the relay coil produces a back-emf.

@jonathanjo Thank you for your comments, I'm going to redraw this tomorrow.
Think of PFW like the Power ON Pin on an ATX PSU, but reversed. The PSU shall turn on when PFW is high (5V), a typical ATX PSU turns on when POW_On is shorted to ground.

MichalPodmanický and Andy aka: Are there any disadvantages to using a 1N4004/7? 50V should be more than enough, just curious.

@CAPLDev I see any advantage by using 4007. The 4007 is even little bit less suited than 4001.

@MichalPodmanický and andayaka are of course correct about back EMF and 1N4001, thanks for picking me up.  I've deleted my previous comment which was just lack of sleep!

What is the basic purpose of the optoisolator here?  You appear to be using the same ground on the input and output sides (so there's no real isolation): is there any reason you can't connect PFW directly to the base of Q1?

@jonathanjo good point. I wanted to isolate PFW coming from this computer's main board. If you are curious, the computer in question is an Apple Quadra 950. It's been a while since I've had a look at the technical documentation on its startup circuit (I had drawn another design using an ATX PSU, so this circuit was completely different), but I guess it's just switching PFW to 5V Standby when the computer needs to be started up. I'll think this through and I my use a "sacrificial" 5V power source just for the relay side so that it'll be completely separated from the computer's main board.

What causes drop in Vcc from 5V to 4.6V? Otherwise it looks quite ok.
I would consider a pull-down resistor between BE of Bjt. A Bjt closes not just by disconnecting the base (by opto), but the base should be pulled to Gnd (by resistor) also. Otherwise the base will be floated.


Thank you VERY much for verifying my circuit, for your suggestion and explanation. I've just added a 10k resistor between the PN2222A's base and ground.
Any reason you set the other resistor to 3K3 instead of 3K74 ?
Regarding the voltage drop, I was considering the worst case scenario. But 4.6V is a bit extreme. I'll redo the calculations for 4.85V.

With 4.85V, Rb should be 3.74 kOhm, perfect. Considering no voltage drop (5V), I get 3.51 kOhm. Knowing that my 5V Standby Power supply is overdimensioned (2A, max load of this application is 1.25A), I should not get a massive drop, except if the wires are too long right?

Some additional current will flow through 10k pull-down (about 70uA). So I decreased 3k7 to 3k3. But anyway, from my practice the 2n2222 has usually beta >100 so you are far away from its limitation.
